# Troubles with certificates

Tags: linux, centos, web

```
[Tue Mar 01 17:29:01.443730 2016] [:error] [pid 12834] Misconfiguration of certificate's CN and virtual name. The certificate CN has mail.[domain.com]. We expected www.[domain.com] as virtual name.
```

Is the error I'm receiving after following the guide linked below. I have recreated the certificate 3 times just in case I messed up and accidentally put mail. but all three times it's returning the same error. And I'm definitely NOT entering mail.[domain.com].

http://www.tecmint.com/create-apache-https-self-signed-certificate-using-nss/2/

There is the guide I've been following. I'm relatively new to dealing with certificates and security and it's all a learning process. I imagine it's something quite easy and simple that I'm overlooking.

I've looked through apaches configuration files to make sure everythings correct. The only thing I can imagine it being is I previously had a dovecot installation on there which I also created keys for but I have since removed dovecot from the server and that wouldn't explain why apache would use those certificates rather than the one I've created while following this guide.

I've been searching for a good few hours for this problem but there's very little information relating to this error message, let alone the problem I'm having specifically.

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            00:a5:9f:f1:2e
        Signature Algorithm: PKCS #1 SHA-256 With RSA Encryption
        Issuer: "CN=allthingscomputing.co.uk,OU=Web evelopment,O=Ace Computer
            s,L=Morecambe,ST=Lancashire,C=GB"
        Validity:
            Not Before: Tue Mar 01 16:48:48 2016
            Not After : Wed Mar 01 16:48:48 2017
        Subject: "CN=allthingscomputing.co.uk,OU=Web evelopment,O=Ace Compute
            rs,L=Morecambe,ST=Lancashire,C=GB"
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: PKCS #1 RSA Encryption
            RSA Public Key:
                Modulus:
                    d5:4b:d2:68:da:8d:e8:fe:65:3f:b5:3d:9a:65:29:c7:
                    fb:1c:c2:36:09:8a:9c:67:0a:81:ff:75:83:45:26:b4:
                    72:33:41:54:98:42:a4:be:eb:43:12:5d:b0:9f:5e:81:
                    e6:45:d0:08:50:ff:36:c7:8a:5c:7d:21:80:1c:3a:c3:
                    4f:bf:ed:b6:09:7f:cc:13:75:4d:39:c9:be:16:22:83:
                    a4:ef:ff:e1:2f:ed:d9:7a:0f:fd:6e:0e:6c:a9:9b:d3:
                    e3:fb:f9:aa:8e:de:39:81:1b:c1:84:ce:b6:59:58:b0:
                    1e:d3:f6:89:04:e3:48:52:b3:c7:41:da:e9:37:58:a4:
                    0a:5c:02:ea:ac:82:7a:68:1a:07:a9:08:4d:17:56:4d:
                    e7:41:a0:02:33:85:a9:40:79:35:28:59:15:f7:7b:05:
                    01:be:82:21:84:09:20:06:96:55:04:e4:bb:25:3d:02:
                    d7:5b:cb:3b:25:e1:56:00:1f:5f:03:3f:c1:64:29:88:
                    1f:be:ad:51:27:18:ee:cf:c5:f4:72:5d:4b:ad:99:a4:
                    19:fd:91:a1:38:75:20:87:f2:bd:cb:ad:82:25:f4:62:
                    45:4c:ac:d2:93:e3:df:64:01:82:bc:76:b4:94:60:b6:
                    db:f1:57:6b:a7:9e:11:df:0c:47:68:55:3e:b1:e4:8f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: PKCS #1 SHA-256 With RSA Encryption
    Signature:
        d4:bc:ad:af:9d:30:17:f8:07:ea:0b:f8:bc:de:d5:32:
        c0:7e:c2:7b:b8:00:4f:b8:c4:c2:a1:00:25:3a:fb:b9:
        aa:77:d7:0a:eb:37:8a:fe:26:96:7b:59:7d:8c:74:18:
        a1:1e:e6:1c:a4:d7:e3:5d:0d:c4:7f:f3:a9:a7:40:25:
        ab:14:dc:01:8b:7f:ad:dd:f3:f4:30:c6:ef:37:06:eb:
        04:8a:b9:49:72:7f:37:cd:d4:1b:fe:e0:ee:9d:98:65:
        55:c4:82:a5:44:e1:7e:ca:c3:96:e5:52:45:e8:b7:06:
        b3:c3:73:92:15:25:00:fa:08:55:36:b2:62:eb:79:a4:
        5b:a0:c4:9e:cd:85:1b:f8:fb:69:6b:74:91:3a:ea:2f:
        13:19:5f:ee:8d:fd:84:09:90:14:31:d6:f4:6d:04:49:
        de:9f:9b:95:64:02:63:30:23:1c:42:5d:7e:e4:83:1e:
        74:67:6f:25:9d:73:cd:d8:a5:61:9e:1c:63:84:cc:d8:
        90:ef:50:b9:8f:92:a9:07:cc:a5:b1:83:ea:5c:a8:e9:
        4c:62:e5:3a:8e:e1:d3:8a:65:fb:67:59:74:6b:6f:20:
        76:5b:a1:53:ff:d1:c4:05:70:87:1c:24:d3:e6:2c:d7:
        af:80:15:8d:07:c1:5e:63:9c:69:92:ff:f1:69:a0:eb
    Fingerprint (SHA-256):
        8F:31:F9:13:86:B7:F3:98:6A:D9:2A:63:26:38:D2:63:AF:B9:1E:96:89:80:9A:48:94:45:B5:FA:6D:40:36:B7
    Fingerprint (SHA1):
        C1:8B:E6:BD:AD:CA:6C:0C:6F:90:2F:EE:19:2F:92:EA:B2:18:E1:DD

    Certificate Trust Flags:
        SSL Flags:
            User
        Email Flags:
            User
        Object Signing Flags:
            User
```

Comment: Add the output of `# certutil -L -d /etc/httpd/alias -n "box1"` (where 'box1' is replaced with the name of your cert) to your question after sanitising it.  Also, at what stage in the guide are you getting the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the answer myself after several painful hours. It was actually the server-cert that mod_nss creates on installation than was incorrectly configured.

I deleted all keys from the database and recreated the keys needed individually from scratch (seemed to be 2, one with the hostname as the CN and one with the domain as the CN).

Comment: It would be nice if you could also put in some details about how you go about doing that.